# suma de elementos dentro de una matriz

Tags: vb

tengo una duda, el programa trata de sumar todos los elementos de la matriz 4x4, ya tengo avance pero el problema es que no me suma todos los elementos, solo las filas y me arroja esos 4 resultados y solo tiene que ser 1 resultado de toda la matriz, que estoy haciendo mal?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim matriz1(4, 4) As Integer
    Dim Suma As Integer


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i = 1 To 4
            For j = 1 To 4
                matriz1(i, j) = InputBox("Ingresa un numero para la matriz 1", "numero", 0)

            Next
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.Text = ""
        Label2.Text = ""
        For i = 1 To 4
            Suma = 0
            For j = 1 To 4
                Label1.Text = Label1.Text & matriz1(i, j) & "   "

                Suma = Suma + matriz1(i, j)
            Next
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text & vbCrLf
            Label2.Text = Label2.Text & Suma & " "
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Estás reiniciando `Suma` en cada iteración del ciclo para `i`.

Comment: mm ya lo puse abajo en j y no, me hace otra cosa rara

Comment: Si quieres tener una sola suma, deberías inicializar `Suma` por fuera de los ciclos. Así, no se va a hacer cero por cada fila. ¿Es eso lo que buscas?

Comment: en este caso me arroja suma de cada fila y va sumando las otras, lo que quiero es que me aparezca un solo resultado y no 4, osea por ejemplo, ejecuto el programa y meto la matriz 

1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16               me arroja  10 36 78 136 y en este caso solo quiero que me 
                                   arroje el 136

Comment: creo que ya lo resolvi, agradezco la atencion y la correccion a la pregunta, disculpa el tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no asignas 0 a `Suma` cada vez que aumentas `i`, va a mantener la suma de todos los elementos.

Así pues, hay que inicializarlo en cero sólo una vez. Si lo haces dentro del ciclo For de i, va a ser cero por cada fila.

Lo mismo, si quieres un solo valor, tienes que pintarlo una única vez, por fuera del For de las filas. No tiene sentido que muevas cosas dentro del ciclo de j porque vas a pintar o hacer cosas por cada elemento individual de la matriz.

La clave acá es que entiendas que, lo que pones entre For y Next pasa tantas veces como iteraciones haya.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.Text = ""
        Label2.Text = ""
        Suma = 0

        For i = 1 To 4
            For j = 1 To 4
                Label1.Text = Label1.Text & matriz1(i, j) & "   "

                Suma = Suma + matriz1(i, j)
            Next
           
        Next

        Label1.Text = Label1.Text & vbCrLf
        Label2.Text = Label2.Text & Suma & " "

    End Sub
```

Comment: agradezco el tiempo y correccion, muchas gracias

Comment: @user214712 con gusto!